# Tem como bloquear acesso externo em uma aplicação?

Tags: java, jboss

É possível bloquear um sistema que está acessando de fora? Tenho um sistema com login e os usuários estão usando Curl PHP para carregar a página inteira no ambiente deles.

Estou usando Java + Jboss.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem sua ncessidade, o mais correto a fazer é criar regras no firewall da sua rede para limitar o acesso.

Abraços